# NFC Subscription Windows phone 8 SDK

Tags: windows-phone, nfc

I have the SmartTags from Sony the content of the tag is:

```
Contents of the NDEF message:
Message size: 41 bytes
Type name: NFC RTD Specification
Record type: U [URI]
semc://liveware/A1/2/NT2/5/smarttags

Raw NDEF message (hex):
D1 01 25 55 00 73 65 6D 63 3A 2F 2F 6C 69 76 65 77 61 72 65 2F 41 31 2F 32 2F 4E 54 32 2F 35 2F 73 6D 61 72 74 74 61 67 73
```

how can I subscribe to this message from windows phone sdk?

I tried the following:

```
proximityDevice.SubscribeForMessage("NDEF:URI.semc://liveware/A1/2/NT2/5/smarttags", AddressOf messageReceived)

'and


proximityDevice.SubscribeForMessage("NDEF:URI.semc", AddressOf messageReceived)
```

I was not able to receive data from the tag.

My question is, how can I subscribe for this data: semc://liveware/A1/2/NT2/5/smarttags

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by subscribe for the data?

Comment: Subscribe so I told Windows Phone that my app is the receiver for such protocol, so the OS will trigger my app when the tag arrived to the phone. btw When I put the tag next to the phone, Windows Store app search for: phone.protocol.semc  thanks

Comment: Have you tried `proximityDevice.SubscribeForMessage("WindowsUri", messageReceived)`?